# Starting several codes and stoping after one of them is finish

Tags: bash

So im starting 4 codes at the same time and I want 3 of them to run in a loop until the 4th program finish.

```
loopProgram1 & loopProgram2 & loopProgram3 & Program4
```

So I want loopPrograms 1,2 and 3 to execute and then all of them exit once program4 is done. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: This seems to be about general bash scripting than Ubuntu, and might be more appropriate on https://stackoverflow.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

hmm, untested

```
children=()
loopProgram1 & children+=($!)
loopProgram2 & children+=($!) 
loopProgram3 & children+=($!)
Program4
kill "${children[@]}"
```